# Issue with Bootstrap Navbar collapse button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I copied this bootstrap template. I have an issue is that when its in mobile mode (small screen) its not showing the sidebar menu(dashboard, menu, content, categories etc) inside the burger. How can I fix it?

My HTML code:

```
 <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"> 
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> 
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>                
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('cms/dashboard')}}">Myhero admin panel</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a target="blank" href="{{ url('')}}">Back to site</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('user/logout')}}">Logout</a></li>                
          </ul>                
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>    
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar ">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar ">
            <li><a href="{{ url('cms/dashboard')}}">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('cms/menu')}}">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('cms/content')}}">Content</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('cms/categories')}}">Categories</a></li> 
            <li><a href="{{ url('cms/products')}}">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="{{ url('cms/orders')}}">Orders</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          @include ('inc.sm')
          @include ('inc.errors') 
        </div> 
      </div>
      @yield('cms_content')
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: That can be achived in CSS please provide your CSS script

Comment: @WojtekT I don't have any CSS for this one

Comment: You will need to include bootstrap e.g `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">` if you dont have that your code will be all over the place.

Comment: For e.g in the website you provide on the bottom it uses this link. <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> so either you could download bootstrap css or you can link it in the `<head>` with the code above

Comment: I have bootstrap cdn

Answer (score 0):

If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.

The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap. To ensure that you have the latest working version of bootstrap you can use cdn to serve the required javascript files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity=[...]>
```

Comment: You can use the same method for CSS as mentionned by Wojtek in the comment above.

Comment: I do have bootstrap cdn inside my code , I just didn't put it here because because it irrelevant to the issue I have :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. Is there anything shown in the console ? For example when you click on the burger.

Comment: Yes. In the console its MyHero admin panel .Inside the Burger only back to site and logout .I need the sidebar menu to be shown also but only when its small screen .